# How to use framebuffer device as a real display (Linux)

Tags: linux-device-driver, framebuffer, x11

Is there a way to make X treat Linux framebuffer device (e.g. built-in virtual framebuffer, vfb) as a real display? Ideally it should appear in system display settings as a configurable monitor. If this requires writing some additional kernel code I'm ok with that, the problem is that I don't know what components are involved in monitor detection and configuration.

Comment: It has been a while since I've developed X or framebuffer drivers, but the framework between the two is very different, although things *may* have changed.  X display drivers are developed as XFree86 drivers.  Quite a lot of code goes around XFree86 drivers to support the X protocol.  In contrast, framebuffer drivers are much more primitive and receive their config parameters at boot time.  They drive the physical display and do not directly work with any higher level protocol, although other code can operate on top of framebuffers.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is not a direct answer to your question, but...

In my LTSP5 configuration I need to add

```
[00:04:23:29:6d:a9]
XSERVER=vesa
```

to get my old PCs with frame buffers to work.  I'm not sure how LTSP uses it, but FYI the mac is for the network card.